# Parse Invalid Json in android?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to convert this json to object it gives error;

```
{"ch":"RSNT_GUEST_DEV_2","m":"{"NEXT_TO_NOTIFY_GUEST_ID":-1,"OP":"DEL","totalWaitTime":72,"ORG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME":72,"guestObj":-1,"NOW_SERVING_GUEST_ID":308,"FROM":"ADMIN","numberofparties":8,"nowServingParty":308,"orgid":2}"}
```

**Error :**

**JSON Exception - Unterminated object at character 33 of {"ch":"RSNT_GUEST_DEV_2","m":"{"NEXT_TO_NOTIFY_GUEST_ID":-1,"OP":"DEL","totalWaitTime":72,"ORG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME":72,"guestObj":-1,"NOW_SERVING_GUEST_ID":308,"FROM":"ADMIN","numberofparties":8,"nowServingParty":308,"orgid":2}"}**

Comment: valid json : `{"ch":"RSNT_GUEST_DEV_2","m":{"NEXT_TO_NOTIFY_GUEST_ID":1,"OP":"DEL","totalWaitTime":72,"ORG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME":72,"guestObj":1,"NOW_SERVING_GUEST_ID":308,"FROM":"ADMIN","numberofparties":8,"nowServingParty":308,"orgid":2}}`. Ask your server-side dev to return in this format only.

Answer (score 0):

this is "{" problem change this u pass in wrong format

Right Format :

```
        {
        "ch": "RSNT_GUEST_DEV_2",
        "m": [
            {
                "NEXT_TO_NOTIFY_GUEST_ID": -1,
                "OP": "DEL",
                "totalWaitTime": 72,
                "ORG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME": 72,
                "guestObj": -1,
                "NOW_SERVING_GUEST_ID": 308,
                "FROM": "ADMIN",
                "numberofparties": 8,
                "nowServingParty": 308,
                "orgid": 2
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid json to check if json is valid or not try [JSON Lint](http://www.jsonlint.com/)

Your json response should be like this

```
{
"ch": "RSNT_GUEST_DEV_2",
"m": {
"NEXT_TO_NOTIFY_GUEST_ID ":"-1,"
"OP":"DEL",
"totalWaitTime ":"72","ORG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME ":"72",
"guestObj":"-1,
"NOW_SERVING_GUEST_ID":"308",
"FROM":"ADMIN ",
"numberofparties ":"8",
"nowServingParty":"308",
"orgid":2}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Json data you have entered is not valid make sure your data like this

```
{
    "ch": "RSNT_GUEST_DEV_2",
    "m": {
        "NEXT_TO_NOTIFY_GUEST_ID ": "-1",
        "OP": "DEL",
        "totalWaitTime ": "72",
        "ORG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME ": "72",
        "guestObj": "-1",
        "NOW_SERVING_GUEST_ID": "308",
        "FROM": "ADMIN ",
        "numberofparties ": "8",
        "nowServingParty": "308",
        "orgid": 2
    }
}
```

Use this online tool for validating your json data http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/